# Secondary screen becomes main screen when i select "PC SCREEN ONLY"

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display-driver

I had 2 screens but recently i added a 3rd screen and this is when my problem started to appear .
My current screen setup:

Main screen : Connected with dvi cable to my video card .

Second screen (used to be main screen before):Connected to video card with hdmi cable.

Third screen : Connected to motherboard with vga cable .

The problem arises when i try to switch to single screen with "PC SCREEN ONLY" because the secondary screen is the one that stays on and the main screen and third screen shut off .

Any solutions to this problem ? Is it a cable problem or a settings one ? Or maybe some drivers need update ?

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange the screens physically to suit, so that the "second screen" connected to the video card with HDMI is the main screen and positioned where you want it.

Then change the order of the logical screens in Windows.

- Right click on blank desktop
- Select Display Settings
- Drag the screens around to suit your layout.